# How do I find out the number of characters in a tmemo component?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tmemo

What I am trying to do is make a button that takes the amount of chars in a memo and output it in a label

I apologise if this seems like a silly question but I am still learning about Delphi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to call the Memo's [`GetTextLen()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.GetTextLen) method:

> Returns the length of the control's text.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := Memo1.GetTextLen;
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Len);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get the length of text in a TMemo.
The fastest is to ask Windows to return the length (It is Windows which implement a TMemo):

```
MemoLen := GetWindowTextLength(Memo1.Handle);
```

or

```
MemoLen := SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
```

Another way is to retrieve the text of the memo and query his length:

```
MemoLen := Length(Memo1.Text);
```

Comment: `Length(Memo1.Text)` will work, but it is the least efficient way to do it, since it has to allocate a new string in memory and copy the entire Memo contents into it, just to query its length. Not a good idea for large texts. Since the Memo knows how many characters it is holding at all times, the best option is to simply ask it what that value is.